# Custom LiveCD without Unity still tries to load ubuntu session. (Failed to load session "ubuntu")

Tags: 11.10, unity, live-cd, customization

I'm trying to create my own Ubuntu LiveCD without Unity.  When lightdm loads is says (Failed to load session "ubuntu").  The autologin fails and then lightdm reloads with a normal login screen.

I can login fine with ubuntu user and if I run "sudo x-session-manager" I still get the error message (Failed to load session "ubuntu").  But that's as far as I can pin point where the problem is.

Where is the default session manager setting?

Lightdm config /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf says that autologin-session=lightdm-autologin but I'm not sure what that is.  Trying to edit this config wouldn't help anyways since casper overwrites it during bootup.

I thought maybe casper sets this but don't see it anywhere in it's config.

Any help?  I want the default to be just 'gnome'.  This would have to be set while creating the LiveCD iso.

Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out.
"http://onubuntu.blogspot.com/2011/09/setting-gnome-shell-as-default-desktop.html"
But the command should be:
"sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --session gnome-shell"
Place it in your script to build the LiveCD "after" lightdm is installed.
This just adds the line "user-session=gnome-shell" to "/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf"

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Copying [user's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107309/custom-livecd-without-unity-still-tries-to-load-ubuntu-session-failed-to-load#comment125293_107309) in his question to an answer.</sub>

> I figured out the solution with the help of this blogpost:
>
> - http://onubuntu.blogspot.sg/2011/09/setting-gnome-shell-as-default-desktop.html
>
> But the command should be:
>
> ```
> sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --session gnome-shell
> ```
>
> Place it in your script to build the LiveCD "after" LightDM is
>   installed. This just adds the line `user-session=gnome-shell` to
>   `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.